# setting server hostname

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, hostname

I'm using ubuntu 10.04 on my server and I'm looking to set the hostname.

Looking around it seems I have to set this in the `/etc/hostname` file, but on my system I do not have one.

Typing `hostname` does return a value

Is there anywhere else this could be set?

Thanks

Comment: Do you actually have a full Ubuntu instance, or is this a chroot, or something?

Comment: AFAIK, every linux system has `/etc/hostname`. Most likely your system is either chrooted, or just screwed up ;)

Answer (score 3):

On Ubuntu server that is the correct location. You just need to add the hostname string only to the file, example:

`echo my-ubuntu-server-name > /etc/hostname` and reboot.

Comment: Actually just run /etc/init.d/hostname.sh start and it will set it for you as well.

Comment: I get `/etc/init.d/hostname.sh start
-bash: /etc/init.d/hostname.sh: No such file or directory`

Comment: No `/etc/init.d/hostname.sh` on my ubuntu server either, maybe you meant `/etc/init.d/hostname`?

Answer (score 0):

This is strange you don't have /etc/hostname

Try to find where your hostname comes from:

```
grep -r 'yourHostName' /etc
```

If you have too many lines (because your hostname is a very common word into your /etc), then use 'hostname' command to set a new one:

```
hostname xxxMyHostNamexxx
```

then restart your search with grep (maybe the missing file will be created by the previous command).

Also search into /usr/